# Pass-by-value/const correctness with C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

Before C++11, I would write my functions like so:

```
struct Color {
    float R,G,B,A;
    Color(float NewR,float NewG,float NewB,float NewA):
        R(NewR),G(NewG),B(NewB),A(NewA)
};
struct Item {
    Color color;

    void SetColor(const Color& new_color)
    {
        color=new_color; // Copy is created
    }
};
```

And then call it like so:

```
a_item.SetColor(Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));

Color new_color(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f); // alternative way 
a_item.SetColor(new_color);
```

Now with C++11, I write my functions like this when applicable:

```
struct Item {
    Color color;

    void SetColor(Color new_color)
    {
        color=std::move(new_color); // No extra copy is created
    }
};
```

And then call it like so:

```
a_item.SetColor(Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)); // already Rvalue

Color new_color(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f); // alternative way 
a_item.SetColor(std::move(new_color));
```

I was wondering if this was a good practice. It seems that when an object ownership is transferred, my functions become pass-by-value with move semantics.

Speaking of const correctness, should my constructor be defined like this:

```
    Color(const float NewR,const float NewG,const float NewB,const float NewA):
        R(NewR),G(NewG),B(NewB),A(NewA)
```

And my SetColor function defined like this?:

```
    void SetColor(const Color new_color)
    {
        color=std::move(new_color); // No extra copy is created
    }
```

Comment: That's not how `std::move` works, at all. There's no free magic.

Comment: Stick to the traditional way, having a simple structure like 'color'

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you explain which part is wrong?

Comment: @Grapes: `std::move` is just a cast. Your comment "no extra copy needed" leads me to believe that you have a very wrong image of what the purpose and effect of that cast are.

Comment: @KerrekSB so a new instance of Color will still be created and a move operator will be called instead of a copy operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the first part, this seems basically fine, but read to the end of this answer. For the second part, you should first know that top-level `const` is stripped from the function's signature. So this

```
void foo( Color c );
```

is identical to

```
void foo( const Color c );
```

For the caller, it therefore makes no difference.
The only difference is when you *define* the function, if you put `const` to a parameter for the definition, the compiler won't modify it. This doesn't make sense in the context you are asking the question: If you want to move the instance somewhere else, it is not `const`.

If you think `const` is the right way to go, use a const reference. Now back to your first question: Using `void f( Color c );` seems easy and in some cases, superfluous copies are avoided. The problem is that this does not work in all cases and on todays compilers. Compared to overloading `const Color&` and `Color&&`, sometimes an additional move is generated. The only benefit is that you need fewer overloads, which might become important once you have multiple parameters.

To explain the difference with code:

```
void X::f( Color c )
{
   this->c = std::move(c); // 1 move=
}

void X::g( const Color& c )
{
   this->c = c; // 1 copy=
}

void X::g( Color&& c )
{
   this->c = std::move(c); // 1 move=
}

X x;
Color c;
x.f(c); // 1 copy-ctor, 1 move=
x.g(c); // 1 copy=
x.f(Color()); // 1 ctor, 1 move=
x.g(Color()); // 1 ctor, 1 move=
x.f(std::move(c)); // 1 move-ctor, 1 move=
x.g(std::move(c)); // 1 move=
```

As you can see, the "traditional" way of using a const reference combined with a C++11 rvalue-reference overload has advantages wrt the number of move-operations (which still do have a cost). Balance it with the simplification of not having overloads and judge for yourself.

Comment: I see, this makes a lot of sense. For some reason, I thought `std::move` would actually take the address of the variable and move it. I'll use `const Color& c` then.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw the "perfect forwarding setter" technique into the mix:

```
struct Item {
    Color color;

    template <typename T>
    void SetColor(T&& new_color)
    {
        color=std::forward<T>(new_color);
    }
};
```

This will move from rvalues, copy from lvalues, and even accepts other types that are convertible to `Color`.